# Overlaying vector data(shapefiles) on Google maps in an android application

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, layer, shapefile

How can we overlay custom shape-files/vector layers on google maps in an android application?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it can be done on Android. What you can do is convert your [shapefile into a KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/vector), create a web map  with the [KML layered](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml), then load the map onto a browser or webview in Android.